# Monolithic vs multiple Mercurial repos for modules within a suite of related applications

Tags: mercurial

At my organization, we'd like to switch from using CVS to Mercurial for a variety of reasons. We've done a lot of investigation when trying to determine how we should organize our Hg repositories based on what we have in our codebase and how we tend to work. We've come up with satisfactory answers to most of our questions, but there's one point that's stumping us a little, and it's driving me mad because the most convenient way to organize the repo for our workflow just seems like the wrong way to go from a conceptual standpoint. I'm trying to figure out whether our perception of how this is "supposed" to work is wrong, or whether we're just bumping up against a legitimate feature gap in the available tooling.

Primarily we maintain a medium sized codebase consisting of a suite of applications that get all get released in the same package. Conceptually you can divide our code into three categories:

1. Shared code
2. Application code for our primary suite (uses the shared code)
3. Miscellaneous small utilities that are infrequently maintained (uses the shared code)

This doesn't seem unusual to me, but I want to stress the point that we maintain the application code and the shared code at the same time and always want them to be bleeding edge with respect to each other. That is, we want all our application builds to always use the latest version and the same version of the shared code. We frequently add to or modify application code and shared code at the same time. Currently, the shared code is in one CVS module, and the applications are all in their own separate modules. The shared code and application modules are checked out such that the shared code gets built once and then linked into each application. We frequently do cvs commits that include changes across shared and application modules at once. We would really like to keep that ability.

I understand that commits in Hg are atomic within repositories -- that's fine but I'd like to be able to diff and commit to an application and a shared library at the "same time" (i.e. I don't care if it's really atomic but I don't want to have to manually do two separate diffs and two separate commit actions).

Conceptually, it seems like it would be correct to have one or a few repos for the shared code, and a separate repo for each application and each little utility program. This means you'd need to check out multiple repos for each build but that isn't a problem for us. The problem is there doesn't seem to be any tooling that lets you view updates or changes on multiple repos at once, or diff multiple repos at once and then sequentially commit them for you. This would be easy to script, but that wouldn't help developers who want to use various GUI frontends to complement the command line.

It seems like in order to be able to commit across multiple codebases at once (from a user's perspective) and keep everything on the bleeding edge together, the only two solutions are:

1. Use a monolithic repo with EVERYTHING in it.
2. Create some subrepos but access/commit everything through a big monolithic "main" repo that contains all the subrepos to keep everything on the latest revisions (which doesn't seem any better than (1) to me).

It can't be that unusual to want to work with multiple "peer" repositories at the same time, even if the actions aren't truly atomic across all of them -- and yet I'm not finding tons of articles or posts clamoring for this ability.

In summary:

1. We would like to organize our code such that we can diff and commit application code and shared code at the same time from the user's perspective (they need not truly be atomic).
2. It seems like we should be putting application code and shared code in separate repositories.
3. Subrepositories tie parent repositories to specific revisions, which we do not want.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your argument against having one big repository with everything in it? If all the code is related and should be kept in-sync with each other, why not do that?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of "medium-sized"? Perhaps an approximate total size of all source files in the suite? Also, #3 in your summary is unclear to me: what do you mean by "tie", and why do you not want it?

Comment: My most compelling argument against having one big repository with everything in it is that if we wanted to share code with other departments via the repository, we'd have to give them access to all the code. Not necessarily a deal breaker but not great.

Comment: wrt "medium sized": I think we have somewhere between 500k and 1m lines of code in the build of our primary application suite. It's not too big for one repository technically, but organizationally I'm trying to figure out if we're looking at this incorrectly.

wrt #3, the fact that parent repos don't get new versions of subrepo code unless they're independently updated or the subrepo is committed through the parent repo would cause problems for us. See http://www.accidentalhacker.com/using-mercurial-subrepositories/

Comment: Don't share code directly with other departments.  Package it as a library, they can then include it as a "sub-module" (using Git terminology).  Also, do software-as-a-service for business functionality.  Force other departments to consume services, not code.  Use JIRA to track missing features and requirements.  For truly common stuff that has no business value, open source it and you both can pull from the same github repo.

Comment: Mercurial subrepos would probably work well for inter-departmental use, but are still awkward for use of the code within our department given the original question. And that is in fact sharing code unless I'm misinterpreting the suggestion. SaaS is a good idea in general too although in many cases it doesn't work for us given the environment in which our software operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my shop, we have many projects that are simply in separate repos, but the main application's repo has 2 other projects in it. One is a module that shares a significant amount of code with the main application, and the other is for database migrations for the application (it's even in a different language). I wanted related changes in both the application and the migrator to be committed together, inseparably. Altogether, all source files in this repo are between 10 and 11 MB.

So if putting everything in one repository is really what makes sense because you don't want to deal with subrepositories, then there's nothing wrong with putting everything in one repository. The one of mine is on the small side of medium, in my opinion. TortoiseHg's source is around 20 MB, OGRE is over 100 MB.

Without knowing more about your projects and their relationships, the impression I get is that a single repository would work just fine, and that you're not looking at this incorrectly.

If you change your mind, [`hg convert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) can help you extract projects into their own repository, maintaining the history of those files.

If the one-repository approach is not for you, then I think [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos) should be given a chance, as that is the only other method I know of for treating multiple repos cohesively that is supported in TortoiseHg (see the [Recommendations](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos#Recommendations) section).

*However, I'm not sure how you would deal with the inter-department access, given that it doesn't seem there is an established subset already shared with others.*

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, the inter-department access problem is more of a theoretical one than a practical one for us at this point so we can cross that bridge when we come to it.

Comment: The overall theme that I'm extracting from this answer is that if an organization wants a group of code to evolve together (not in several independent groups) than that group of code should be together in one repository. Or, as a corollary, if you want to separate projects into multiple repositories then your workflow should allow them to evolve independently or control that evolution. Does this sound correct? Do others agree with this answer?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds correct to me, given the known tools (subrepos are sortof a hybrid). As for agreement, consider the state of this entire Q&A: 5 upvotes and 5 faves to your question; 0 upvotes to my answer; 0 other answers. I interpret this to mean that I'm playing Captain Obvious, stating what is available (nothing insightful or new), while some want better tools to be able to do what you describe, but nobody seems to have those tools.

Comment: That's my interpretation too. I was going to mark yours as the answer, but stopped myself earlier because it seems like the answer is "that's the best compromise due to lack of tooling support" rather than "a monolithic repo is really the right way to go here". I think I'm ready to accept it and move on, though :)

Comment: Well, for some situations, it is the right answer (such as the anecdote I opened with regarding a couple of my own projects). I just don't like saying "this is the right way for you" with only a cursory understanding of your circumstances -- sometimes there's that single detail that is a show-stopper for an otherwise reasonable solution.

Comment: The thing that's most likely to be a problem for us for a single large repo is sharing smaller sections of code with other departments. But I think we could handle that by breaking that code out into subrepos for the other departments, and still treating our parent repo as a big monolithic one.

Comment: I wanted to follow up (wow, it's been a while!) to update that we did end up going with a monolithic repository, which is fairly large (a couple gigabytes for the backing repo) and do not regret it a bit.